Regarding SSAS data cube
if we have db view used in dsv , that uses some function to calculate the columns.
And there is any requirements to change the column (no column name and type chaged ) then I need to re deploy the changes again in server.
In my case latest values are not showing in pivot excel even after making changes in functions
Update the pivot table without deploying the cube again
